# Parsing date in the format of "Nov 4"

Tags: java, scala, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a date in the format of `Nov 4` using java's `SimpleDateFormat` class. I've looked over the documentation and see that

```
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07

d   Day in month    Number  10
```

Are the two format symbols I need to try and use. I've tried to code it up

```
        val dateString = "Nov 4"
        val dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M d")
        val date = dateFormatter.parse(dateString)
```

and I get an error saying that `Nov 4` is an unparseable date. How can I parse this date using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: `M` is a month with one or two digits - for the short written version use `MMM`.

Comment: Read further into the documentation, the part about how many pattern letters are used for text vs for numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d");
Date date = new Date();     
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Output: Nov 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd");
```